# T-SQL XML Closing Tag On Empty Elements

Tags: sql, xml

I am trying to write a query that returns XML using t-sql. When I run a query that does not have any sibling elements the closing tags are left as is and NOT converted to self closing tags.

```
create table #seg
(
    HouseHoldExternalId int,
    Id int
)

insert into #seg
select 2534640, 265 union
select 2534644, 265 union
select 2534650, 265 union
select 2534661, 265 union
select 2534669, 265 union
select 2534684, 265 union
select 2534689, 265 union
select 2534692, 265 union
select 2534694, 265 union
select 2534698, 265

select
    1 as 'Id',
    (
        select 
            HouseHoldExternalId as 'HouseHoldExternalId',
            (
                select null as 'Blank',
                (
                    select  Id as 'Id', 1 as 'Status',
                    (
                        select  '' for xml path (''), type
                    )
                    from    #seg as aa
                    where   aa.HouseHoldExternalId = a.HouseHoldExternalId 
                    for xml raw ('Segment'), type
                )
                for xml raw ('HouseHoldSegments'), type
            )
            from #seg as a
            for xml raw ('HouseHold'), type
    )
    for xml raw ('retailer'), type
```

A snippet from the resulting xml shows the full closing tag.

```
<Segment Id="265" Status="1"></Segment>
```

When I try to adjust my query to return a result with sibling elements, the closing tags are changed to be self closing. How can I get the full closing to stay?

```
select
    1 as 'Id',
    (
        select 
            HouseHoldExternalId as 'HouseHoldExternalId',
            (
                select null as 'Blank',
                (
                    select  Id as 'Id', 1 as 'Status',
                    (
                        select  '' for xml path (''), type
                    )
                    from    #seg as aa
                    where   aa.HouseHoldExternalId = a.HouseHoldExternalId 
                    for xml raw ('Segment'), type
                )
                for xml raw ('HouseHoldSegments'), type
            )
            from #seg as a
            for xml raw ('HouseHold'), type
    ),
    (
        select 
            HouseHoldExternalId as 'HouseHoldExternalId',
            (
                select null as 'Blank',
                (
                    select  Id as 'Id', 1 as 'Status',
                    (
                        select  '' for xml path (''), type
                    )
                    from    #seg as aa
                    where   aa.HouseHoldExternalId = a.HouseHoldExternalId 
                    for xml raw ('Segment'), type
                )
                for xml raw ('HouseHoldSegments'), type
            )
            from #seg as a
            for xml raw ('HouseHold'), type
    ) 
    for xml raw ('retailer'), type
```

A snippet from the resulting xml shows the self closing tag which I do not want.

```
<Segment Id="265" Status="1" />
```

Comment: @Backs - I am creating a file that will be parsed by a third party which requires the full closing tag

Comment: i spent a month, trying to do this, but nothing :(